# Using Excel VBA to insert a hyperlink at a Word bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, hyperlink

I'm developing an Excel macro with VBA to create add a hyperlink in a Word template.  I've added a bookmark in the template, where the hyperlink should go, called "WebAdd".  I've tried using the code below and am getting a Type Mismatch error.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

"MyWebAdd" is the web address for the hyperlink

```
WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyWebAdd, Address:="", SubAddress:="WebAdd", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=MyWebAdd
```

I've also used the following code.  It puts the web address at the bookmark but it is not a hyperlink a user can click on.  The bookmark name has the correct bookmark and the MyWebAdd variable has the correct web address

```
WrdApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(BookMarkName).Select
WrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
WrdApp.Selection.TypeText MyWebAdd
```

Thanks for your help with this issue.....

Comment: Did you look up the [online help article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks.add)? The very first example shows you what you need to do.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt............I did look at that article several times.  I tried to adapt the bookmark example (#2) to my situation.  Example #1 doesn't deal with a bookmark so I didn't use it.  I need the hyperlink in a specific place in the Word document.  Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first example in the online help shows you that the anchor needs to be a `Range` not a string.

```
With WrdApp.ActiveDocument
  .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Bookmarks(BookmarkName).Range, _
  Address:=MyWebAdd, _
  TextToDisplay:=MyWebAdd
End With
```

Comment: @TimothyRylatt...........Thank you very much.  That did the trick and did exactly what I was trying to do.  I appreciate the help.  Have a great rest of the day......